# select row based on value of another row in R

Tags: r, row

EDIT: to make myself clear, I know how to select individual rows and I know there are many different ways of doing it. I want to write a code that will work no matter what the actual value of the rows is, so it works over a larger dataframe, that is, I don't have to change the code based on the content. So instead of saying, select row 1, then 3, it'll say, select row one, then row [value in row 1 column Z] then row [value in column Z from the row just selected] and so on - so my question is, how to tell R to read that value as row number

I'm trying to figure out how to select and save a row based on a value in another row, so that I get get a new df with row 1(aA), then go to row 3 and save it (cC), then go to row 2 etc.

```
X  Y  Z 

a  A  3
b  B  5
c  C  2
d  D  1
e  E  NA
```

Knowing the row number, I can use rbind which will give me the following

```
rbind(df[1, ], df[3, ]

a A 3
c C 2
```

But I want R to extract the number 3 from the column not to explicitly tell it which row to pick - how do I do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `while` loop to keep on selecting rows until `NA`  occurs or all the rows are selected in the dataframe.

```
all_rows <- 1
next_row <- df$Z[all_rows]

while(!is.na(next_row) || length(all_rows) >= nrow(df)) {
  all_rows <- c(all_rows, next_row)
  next_row <- df$Z[all_rows[length(all_rows)]]
}

result <- df[all_rows, ]

#  X Y  Z
#1 a A  3
#3 c C  2
#2 b B  5
#5 e E NA
```

Comment: Hi again, this works well on a small set, but on a larger file it gets stuck in an infinite run... would you be willing to explain the code a bit so I can understand what's wrong? for example, why is the first statement larger than nrow?

Comment: This is `length(all_rows) >= nrow(df)` to stop the `while` loop when there is no `NA` in the data. So if `all_rows` includes all the values in the column then it stops the loop.

Answer (score -2):

if you know which rows of which column that you want, you can use ;

```
df <- read.table(textConnection('X  Y  Z 

a  A  3
b  B  5
c  C  2
d  D  1
e  E  NA'),
header=T)

desired_rows <- c('a','c')

df2 <- df[df$X %in% desired_rows,]

df2
```

**output;**

```
  X     Y         Z
  <fct> <fct> <int>
1 a     A         3
2 c     C         2
```

Comment: I don't know, that's the point, I'm trying to learn how to specify a row value based on a value in a different row and column

Comment: you can apply the method that I answered, sound possible

Comment: yes, to select a specific pair, but what I want is to say "go to row number specified in column X", then, in row number 3, it'll again be "go to row specified in column X", which is row 2 etc., in that order.

Comment: This does not answer the question, this is just base subsetting with known index, the OP wants the index to be extracted from row Z, not as predefined index